# Microsoft Excel use different multipliers based on text value in other column

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-statements

I am trying to calculate a value which is using a different multiplier depending on the cell value (text) in a column (K):

The text value options are "peak","shoulder","off-peak" which are listed in column K
The rate options (multipliers): J2 for peak, J4 for shoulder, J6 for off-peak

I then want to set up a formula in column L to multiply the value in column D with the appropriate multiplier based on the text value in column K.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

##### IFS Function (Option 1)

The [IFS function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) checks whether one or more conditions are met, and returns a value that corresponds to the first TRUE condition. IFS can take the place of multiple nested IF statements and is much easier to read with multiple conditions.
`=IFS([True1, Value1, True2, Value2, True3, Value3,...)`

```
=D2*IFS( K2="peak", $J$2,
         K2="shoulder",$J$4,
         K2="off-peak",$J$6 )
```

[image]

##### Nested IF Functions (Option 2)

The [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) allows you to make logical comparisons between a value and what you expect.  An IF statement can have two results. The first result is if your comparison is True, and the second is if your comparison is False.

You can nest IF functions so that the value of TRUE or FALSE is another IF function.

```
=D2*IF(K2="peak",$J$2,
       IF(K2="shoulder",$J$4,
          IF(K2="off-peak",$J$6)))
```

[image]